# Continuity of Complex Function of Two Functions Dependent of Re(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

[image]

I believe this function is continuous at $0$ and hence is a continuous function.

It's continuous if $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0^-}\bar{z} = 0$, is that right?

If so, how do I prove that that's the limit? It seems really intuitive for me. It sounds as intuitive as, for example, $y=-x$ and hence $\lim{y}_{x \rightarrow 0^-} = 0$. Does it need proof?

Answer (score 1):

No. To show continuity of $f$ at $0$ you need to show that $\lim_{|z|\to 0} f(z)=0$ instead of just showing that the left side limit converges to $0$. To show continuity see that $$ |f(z)-f(0)|=|f(z)|=|z|$$
Since $|z|=|\overline{z}|$. So for any $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta =\epsilon$. Then $|z-0|=|z|<\delta$ implies that $|f(z)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $z=0$.